# How to hide "add to card" button after the product has been paid?

Tags: commerce

How to hide "add to card" button after the product has been paid for once?

I'm using [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

Can somebody share the code or link?

Comment: Paid for once ever or once per user?

Comment: what you mean of 'Paid'? 
user bought it before in any time in past?(or want disable add to cart when he/she added it to cart once)